# How does one integrate by parts $x^3 e^{-ax^2}$?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to use integration by parts and evaluate

$$\int x^3 e^{-ax^2}dx$$

So far I have gotten it to

\begin{align}
u&= x^3\\
du &= 3x^2 dx \\
dv & = e^{-ax^2}dx\\ 
v &= \int e^{-ax^2}dx
\end{align}

$$\int x^3 e^{-ax^2}dx = -\frac{x^2}{2a} e^{-ax^2} - \int \bigg \lbrace \int e^{-ax^2} dx \bigg \rbrace 3x^2 dx $$

I keep screwing up this integral

$$\int e^{-ax^2}dx $$

and Wolfram Alpha gives me something unintelligible for it.

Can someone help me understand what I am missing? I think if someone could just evaluate
$$\int e^{-ax^2}dx $$ for me, I could complete the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your current choice of $u$ and $dv$ is that $\displaystyle\int e^{-ax^2}\,dx$ is not expressible in terms of elementary functions.

Fortunately, there is more than one way to break up $x^3e^{-ax^2}\,dx$ into $u$ and $dv$.

Try setting $u = x^2$ and $dv = xe^{-ax^2}\,dx$. Then, $du = 2x\,dx$ and $v = -\dfrac{1}{2a}e^{-ax^2}$.

Comment: Super. That solved everything. Why did it need to be in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: My point is that you can't write down the antiderivative of $e^{-ax^2}$ using just functions that you've seen in calculus/precalc. This is why Wolfram Alpha gave you something in terms of the error function.

Answer (score 0):

Let $-ax^2=t\implies -2ax\ dx=dt$ or $x\ dx=-\large \frac{dt}{2a}$ $$\int x^3e^{-ax^2}\ dx=\int x^2e^{-ax^2}(x\ dx)=\int \left(\frac{-t}{a}\right)e^t\left(\frac{-dt}{2a}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2a^2}\int t\ e^t\ dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{2a^2}\left(t\int e^t-\int 1\cdot  \ e^t\ dt\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2a^2}\left(t-1\right)e^t+C$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2a^2}\left(ax^2+1\right)e^{-ax^2}+C$$